# Buffer on line not rounded on both ends in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, buffer, line

[image: Buffer on Lines not rounded on both ends]

As you can see in the image, after using the 'Buffer' geoprocessing tool on ArcMap 10.2, the buffer is not symmetric in some cases, and is therefore flat on one end (as shown in the image). The Buffer setting I have used in the 'Buffer' settings is 'Rounded'.

The line layer I use to add buffer, is made by drawing lines between points using the 'Lines to Points' geoprocessing tool.

Thoughts?

Comment: The line might be bent back on itself so the start and end points may not actually be where you think they'd be

Comment: Interesting. Will check it out and let you know.

Comment: Bend line still produces rounded buffer

Comment: @FelixIP is correct - I have been able to test now and found the buffers still produced fine with a line bent back on itself

Comment: What are the coordinates and coordinate system of that line?  What are all of the parameter values that you used to perform the buffering?  What were the precise steps that you used to run the Buffer tool i.e. where within the Geoprocessing framework did you run it?